# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 300

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to write a PHP code to explode all the lines by `"\n"` and add a `<hr>` tag in it.
This is how the code works:

1. It is a simple code to request data from a Whois server and match the query with it's domain extension.
   For E.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), It will take the .com part and try to match it with different extensions. Also, it Searches for the other data too.
2. Now I want to add some `<hr>` tags to separate and make it compitable for my website.

This is the result when I query `facebook.com`

```
Domain Name: FACEBOOK.COM
Registry Domain ID: 2320948_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.registrarsafe.com
Registrar URL: http://www.registrarsafe.com
Updated Date: 2020-03-10T18:53:59Z
Creation Date: 1997-03-29T05:00:00Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2028-03-30T04:00:00Z
Registrar: RegistrarSafe, LLC
Registrar IANA ID: 3237
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abusecomplaints@registrarsafe.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1-650-308-7004
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited
Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited
Name Server: A.NS.FACEBOOK.COM
Name Server: B.NS.FACEBOOK.COM
Name Server: C.NS.FACEBOOK.COM
Name Server: D.NS.FACEBOOK.COM
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of whois database: 2020-06-23T17:31:31Z <<<
For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp
NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.
TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and
automated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or
modify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry
Services' ("VeriSign") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for
information purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information
about or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not
guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide
by the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only
for lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data
to: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone,
or facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes
that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation,
repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly
prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.
The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.
```

Now I want to beautify it a little with some PHP code.
a. I wanna separate this data into little sections.

```
<!-- Basic Details -->
Domain Name: FACEBOOK.COM
Registry Domain ID: 2320948_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.registrarsafe.com
Registrar URL: http://www.registrarsafe.com
Updated Date: 2020-03-10T18:53:59Z
Creation Date: 1997-03-29T05:00:00Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2028-03-30T04:00:00Z
Registrar: RegistrarSafe, LLC
Registrar IANA ID: 3237
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abusecomplaints@registrarsafe.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1-650-308-7004


<hr>
<!-- Domain Status -->  
...

<hr>
<!-- Other Details -->
...
```

I noticed that number of lines does not change when you change the domain name. So I am trying to separate the first 10 lines. then next 4 lines and so on. and Add the

---

tags in the middle.

The Data which my program collects, stores in a `$result` variable.
Now this is my code

```
    $detailedProperties = [];
    $finalArray = [];
    $words = explode("\n", $result);
    array_push($detailedProperties, $words);
    $lengthOfWords = count($detailedProperties);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $lengthOfWords; $i++) {
        if((string)$i[0]) {
            
            $value = '<div class="container">'.
                    '<hr>'.     
                '</div>';
                array_push($finalArray, $value) ;
        }
        $value = "$i[0]"."\n"."$i[1]"."\n"."$i[2]"."\n"."$i[3]"."\n"."$i[4]"."\n"."$i[5]"."\n"."$i[6]"."\n"."$i[7]"."\n"."$i[8]"."\n"."$i[9]"."\n";
        array_push($finalArray, $value);
        if($i[10]) {
            
            $value = '<div class="container">'.
                    '<hr>'.     
                '</div>';
                array_push($finalArray, $value) ;
        }
        if($i[16]) {
            
            $value = '<div class="container">'.
                    '<hr>'.     
                '</div>';
                array_push($finalArray, $value) ;
        }
        if($i[20]) {
            
            $value = '<div class="container">'.
                    '<hr>'.     
                '</div>';
                array_push($finalArray, $value) ;
        }
    }
    
    return 
        "<div class='row cta-content'>".
            "<div class='offerdescription'>".
                "<div class='container' style='font-size:20px'>".
                    // $detailedProperties;
                    
                    "<span class='search-results'><strong>$domain</strong> Domain lookup results from <strong>$whoisserver</strong> Server\n\n</span>" . $finalArray.
                "</div>".
            "</div>".
        "</div>";
```

Now the error log:

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 300

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 307

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 309

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 316

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 323

Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/about/include/whois.php on line 338
```

And the Programs prints
`Array` instead of the data I have attached above. (The facebook data)

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$i` is an integer starting with 0. You can't access an array value of an integer. You are  starting it all with `if((string)$i[0])` and keep trying to use it from there.

Comment: Wow, this would be so much shorter and easier with `array_slice`!

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, I figured it out now. Thanks for the udpate

Comment: @aynber Can you please tell me a little more. I am using Array index ```count```. Isnt it an integer type?

Comment: If you mean `$lengthOfWords`, yes, that's an integer. But so is `$i`, because you initialize it as an integer on your `for` loop, at `for ($i = 0; $i < $lengthOfWords; $i++)`. So the first loop, `$i` will be 0, then 1, then 2. So you cannot access `$i[0]`. `$detailedProperties` is an array, with an array of `$words` for each child array. You'd need to figure out how to get the data from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be shortened and/or improved, but it's better than what you have:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $result);
$value = "\n<div class='container'><hr></div>\n";
$output[] = implode("\n", array_slice($lines, 0, 11));  //get first 11
$output[] = implode("\n", array_slice($lines, 11, 6));  //get next 6
$output[] = implode("\n", array_slice($lines, 17));     //get remaining
$finalArray = implode($value, $output);

return 
    "<div class='row cta-content'>
        <div class='offerdescription'>
            <div class='container' style='font-size:20px'>
                <span class='search-results'><strong>$domain</strong> Domain lookup results from <strong>$whoisserver</strong> Server\n\n</span>
                $finalArray
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>";
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes it can be improved and it is 10 times better than my code. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$i[10]` is a syntax error, `$m[n]` means retrieving the array value of $m with the associated key n.

It should be like this:

```
if($i <= 10) {
    //...
} elseif($i > 10 && $i <=16) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Why cant we be Explicit with arrays like ```$i[10]```?

Comment: `$i` is not an array `for($i = 0` and `$i++` it's an integer.